# Can Defenders die?

Tags: fortnite-save-the-world

Defenders are helpful during missions, especially when you're alone, however they need to be kind of close to the action to actual get involved (which can lead to them taking quite a bit of damage).

I'm aware that at the end of the mission, or if the defender post platform is destroyed that they give back the weapon/ammo and the defender goes back to your inventory/squad.

As also mentioned [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FORTnITE/wiki/faq#wiki_defenders):

> " - What happens my stuff when a defender leaves the mission or the
>   mission ends?
>
> Any time a mission ends or the defender leaves the mission, all items
>   and ammo will go back to the players backpack."

My question that I haven't been able to figure out is, **if a defender dies, do they just go back to your inventory/squad, or do they die entirely and get removed from your inventory/squad?**

I just want to know if I should be managing my defenders better to try and prohibit their deaths.

Comment: Ive had defenders lose all their health, and they just enter a revivable state. Is there a way they can actually die? I havent experienced that yet, as i always revive them immediately

Comment: Oh they enter a revivable state? I wasn't aware. The only time I've seen a defender disappear was when their platform was broken by a lobber. If that's all, then honestly sounds like an answer if you want to post that.

Comment: oooh, interesting. I hadn't thought of that case. I can confirm they do become revivable when their health drops but i have no idea about pad destruction.

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that in the question as I knew about that. (It took a second to actual realize that's what happened). My question was for when their health hits 0 which I couldn't test or find online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From personal experience, I can confirm that when a Defender loses all their life, they collapse where they're standing and start calling out for help.

Players can then hold the interact button (<kbd>X</kbd>  on Xbox, and <kbd>□</kbd>on PS4) to revive the defender and get them back in the fight.

I personally have never waited very long to revive one, but I did not see a visible timer, so I assume they remain revivable for the rest of the level.

Comment: This answers it thanks. I'd add that it's square on PS4. I'd also be interested if there is a timer. When a teammate or yourself dies you have a timer before you respawn at the start vs being revived/using up a life.

Comment: Not a problem, edited accordingly